# Get the highlighted item in the DropDownList of combobox when user moving mouse over the items?

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, combobox

The context is user clicks on a combobox and it drops down a list (called Drop down list), user may move mouse over the dropped list before selecting a one, I would like to get the highlighted item when user doing so. This can be used for some purposes, for example display the hovered item text in another control on my form....

Could I have any solution for this?

Thank you!